# Не могу записать данные c print_r в mysqli

Tags: api, mysqli

Все перепробовал. Вопрос в следующем: вывод данных с API через json и показываю через print_r($asdf, true). Если проверять сам вывод то он работает, но как только начинаю записывать данные в mysqli...все, пишет что успешно добавлено, а в БД не показывает. Ошибок нету вообще никаких. Записываю через функцию.
Пример кода функции:

```
    $datanew = file_get_contents( 
"https://api.openprocurement.org/api/2.4/tenders?opt_pretty=1&descending=1&limit=2" );
$encode = json_decode( $datanew );
    function get_list_tender_in($encode)
    {
foreach ($encode->data as $keys => $value) {
            $id_tender = print_r( $value->id, true );
            $datanew_new = file_get_contents( "https://api.openprocurement.org/api/2.4/tenders/$id_tender" );
            $encode_new = json_decode( $datanew_new );
 true );
            // Основные переменные для записи
            $id_tender = print_r( $value->id, true );
            $datanew_new = file_get_contents( "https://api.openprocurement.org/api/2.4/tenders/$id_tender" );
            $encode_new = json_decode( $datanew_new );
            $name_of_tender = print_r( $encode_new->data->title, true );
            $name_of_tender_new = print_r('asdasdsad');

            $id_tender_mysqli = print_r( $encode_new->data->tenderID, true );
            $id_tender_mysqli = mysqli_real_escape_string(connect_db(), $id_tender_mysqli);
            $cost_of_tender = number_format( print_r( $encode_new->data->value->amount, true ), 2, '.', '' );
            $costumer_tender = print_r( $encode_new->data->procuringEntity->name, true );
            $status_tender = print_r( $encode_new->data->status, true );
            $auction_url = print_r( $encode_new->data->tenderID, true );
            echo print_r( $encode_new->data->title, true );
            //записываем данные в БД
            $insert = connect_db()->query( "INSERT INTO tenders(`name_of_tender`) VALUES ($name_of_tender_new)");
            echo print_r( $encode_new->data->title, true );//вывод работает
        }
}
```

Помогите)

Comment: а да, пробовал вручную вписывать в переменную данные, то нормально записывает в базу. Вывожу через php. Код, который выводит: <form method="POST">
<button type="submit" name="insert_in" class="btn btn-warning">Записать данные в БД!</button>
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['insert_in'])){
get_list_tender_in($encode);
echo "Успешно добавлено!";
}


$mysqli_connect->close();

Comment: попробовал запись через mysqli_real_escape_string. Записало, но пишет только одну запись,  и после добавления в конце запроса insert "or die("");" пишет постоянно еррор